# Boost data-driven test output: "Assertion occurred in a following context"

Tags: c++, boost-test

I have a question regarding the output of the following minimal example that uses Boost test.

```cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE ExampleTestSuite
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using boost::unit_test::test_suite;
using boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite;

#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
namespace bdata = boost::unit_test::data;

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(ExampleTest, bdata::xrange(2), testDatum) {

    int exp = testDatum == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(testDatum, exp);
}
```

If I run this test with `./boost_testing --log_level=all`, I get the following output:

```
Running 2 test cases...
Entering test module "ExampleTestSuite"
boost_testing.cpp(11): Entering test suite "ExampleTest"
boost_testing.cpp(11): Entering test case "_0"
boost_testing.cpp(15): info: check testDatum == exp has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    testDatum = 0;
boost_testing.cpp(11): Leaving test case "_0"
boost_testing.cpp(11): Entering test case "_1"
boost_testing.cpp(15): info: check testDatum == exp has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    testDatum = 1;
boost_testing.cpp(11): Leaving test case "_1"
boost_testing.cpp(11): Leaving test suite "ExampleTest"
Leaving test module "ExampleTestSuite"

*** No errors detected
```

What is the meaning of the output line `Assertion occurred in a following context: testDatum = 0;`? Does it indicate an issue with the way that I have set up the data-driven test case or can I safely ignore it?

Comment: If you're more careful with parenthesis, does the error go away?

`int exp = (testDatum == 0) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: @NeilGatenby thanks for having a look but no, it makes no difference. I get this output on all Boost data-driven tests that I use and not just on this minimal working example.

Comment: Maybe [line 262 of the source code](https://github.com/boostorg/test/blob/412fcc6e12a873c31839b2ddcedc61dfcbc7e562/include/boost/test/impl/compiler_log_formatter.ipp) is somewhere you could start looking?  Is it reporting success? (Not clear to me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the message is confusing: this is in fact the description of the assertion context for the test `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(testDatum, exp)`, and in fact this is not describing an error, but the context attached to the check. If you change `--log_level=all` to something else, or user another output format, this should go away.

Feel free to raise an issue on [Boost.Test](https://github.com/boostorg/test) project

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess it is reasonable to expect this type of "lower level" output when `--log_level=all` so I will not raise an issue for it.